# How do you create a UIImageView programmatically in Xcode

Tags: xcode, uiimageview

I just want to make an UIImageView programmatically that displays a 20by20 dot at point (50,50).(The image of the dot is called draw.png).  For some reason nothing shows up on the screen.

Heres my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
UIImageView *dot =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50,50,20,20)];
dot.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"draw.png"];
[self.view addSubview:dot];


[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib
}
```

Comment: Your code for adding imageView is right, show more code in this method or anything related.

Comment: Make sure that draw.png exists and if you are testing in device, check for case sensitivity.

Comment: I added the rest on top  I want it to be made once the program begins

Answer (score 39, accepted):

First, make sure draw.png exists in your project and that you are referencing it exactly (so if it's draw.PNG you should put `@"draw.PNG"`).  Also, call `[super viewDidLoad]` before everything.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib

  UIImageView *dot =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50,50,20,20)];
  dot.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"draw.png"];
  [self.view addSubview:dot];

}
```

Answer (score 7):

Try this :-

```
 UIImageView *imageview = [[UIImageView alloc]
 initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 20, 20)];
 [imageview setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"AppleUSA1.jpg"]];
 [imageview setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
 [self.view addSubview:imageview];
```

Answer (score 3):

In Swift :

```
   let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 20, height: 20))
     imageView.image = UIImage(named: "draw.png")
     self.view.addSubview(imageView)
```

Answer (score 2):

This code is correct. Make sure `draw.png` exists in your project. You can do it by checking if `[UIImage imageNamed:@"draw.png"]` doesn't return `nil`.

Also, make sure you don't have another view on top of your image view.

Comment: I was missing `.png` from the image string reference. +1

Answer (score 2):

make sure that image is in your project..

```
UIImageView *imgView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 50, 50)];
[imgView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"xyz.jpg"]];//if your images extension is .png than no need to write extension of an image..
[self.view addSubview:imgView];
```

Answer (score 2):

This code is perfect match an UIImageView:

```
UIImageView *IMG_view= [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20 ,50 ,40 ,40)];
[IMG_view setTag:100]; //[IMG_view setTag:indexPath.row];
IMG_view.layer.borderWidth= 0.5 ;
IMG_view.layer.borderColor= [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];
IMG_view.layer.cornerRadius= 3;
IMG_view.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
[self.view addSubview:IMG_view];
IMG_view.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Loading_50x50.png"];
```